# How do I create/add a sql server compact edition db in vs2010?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have vs2010 ultimate installed and sql server 2008 developer. I created a package using the openAuth Extension from the online gallery and can not find an option to add a sql server CE db to my project. I tried changing the target framework to 4.0 and still nothing.

I see a type that says SQL Server Database, but I believed that was for a full blown db to attach to sql server.

Where is compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to add it in the Server explorer even if it's new.

Here is the link on how to do it.
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983322(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: nope, app_data was there and that's where I tried to create the item. In addition I have now started up a regular asp.net mvc project and it's also not available from the app_data add there.

Comment: I forgot about the server explorer part...I edited my answer to correct it. After that vs2010 will add it to your app_data folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ljM5.png

I fix my problem running SSCEVSTools-esn.msi from the vs2010 dvd.
D:\Visual Studio 2010\WCU\SSCE

Comment: Image is in ... spanish or portugese, but somewhat interpretable.